# Asp.net inline expression wasn't outputed in the js file

Tags: asp.net

All, If I add an inline expression in the aspx page like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var notAcceptError='<%= lblMessage%>';//the actually value is "test message"
</script>
```

As we know. There should exist a variable named `lblMessage` is defined in the code-behind file of aspx.
in this way , everything is fine. 
But If I move the above code into a js file which is linked by the same page.
the output of expression failed. seems the asp.net can't recognize this expression.
I can't understand why this doesn't work in the linked external js file. In my understanding. writing in the aspx or an external js is the same. thanks.

Comment: You will have to call a method from the aspx page, which provides lblMessage as a parameter. Then in the external JS file method that was called from the aspx page you assign the parameter to var noAcceptError.

Comment: js is a static page, the IIS wont process through the .NET compiler. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong. ASPX files are parsed and evaluated, whereas JS files are served from the server without any parsing or evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

The asp.net inline expression only work in `.aspx` files. It will not work in `.js` file because `.js` files served as static files and are not parsed at runtime.

If you really want to use a variable value in code-bind file into the `js` you can do like this.

In your aspx file do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var notAcceptError = '<%= lblMessage%>'; //the actually value is "test message"
</script>

<%-- please note the external file is referenced after the javascript variable --%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfile.js">
</script>
```

And inside your `myjsfile.js` use the variable like this

```
alert(notAcceptError);
```